# Block IP address through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to block some IPs through htaccess to visit the site to prevent malicious attacks an example IP is : 172.30.1.193
I am using this rule to block the IP

```
order allow,deny
deny from 172.30.1.193
allow from all
```

but i am recieving error of forbidden 403

Comment: You should block them on the firewall. if you're using linux, use IPtables, so that they don't even reach the web server.

Comment: thanks for the reply can we block it through htaccess anyhow ?

Comment: What version of apache? That matters